# Is there a environment variable that gives out version of ubuntu and version of the kernel?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Is there a environment variable that gives out version of ubuntu and another that gives out version of the kernel?

I am guessing the answer is no as `printenv | grep 14.04` gave nothing but I thought I would ask anyway as it would save me from having to declare it by running an extra command in a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked all the answers provided as they all confirmed what I suspected, however I think doing the following would be better for what I am looking for:

There is a file in ubuntu: `/etc/lsb-release`

I just discover this now by looking at the scripts within `/etc/update-motd.d` in particular `/etc/update-motd.d/00-header`

This file, although not executable, contains variables with ubuntu version info that are run while motd messages are passed by doing the following:

`[ -r /etc/lsb-release ] && . /etc/lsb-release`

Meaning basically, as I understand it, if this file exists and it's readable run it with bash.

So at least within the Ubuntu environment, if I were to include that line in my script or just the `. /etc/lsb-release` that would provide me with all the variables I need without having to resort to any commands.

Answer (score 9):

No. You have to use the `lsb_release` and `uname` commands respectively to get the versions of Ubuntu and the kernel.

```
$ lsb_release -sr
14.04
$ lsb_release -sc
trusty
$ uname -r
3.13.0-65-generic
```

Alternatively, you can parse certain files, but unless you have a strong reason to do so, better use these commands.

Comment: One could declare appropriate variables in `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`

Comment: @Nephente one could do a lot of things, but that won't "save [OP] from having to declare it by running an extra command in a script".

Comment: Of course, that was just a suggestion for OP not a criticism of your answer  :-)